# How to use Fabric.js to achieve a masking effect in front-end canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

```
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVmdQ.png)
[mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyBIF.png)
[background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWNVS.png)
```

I have two image，one for background，the other for the mask，eventually make up together.
We can see the colorful heart icon is cover by the phone camera, I am confuse how to do it like this with canvas, I hope to who can give me some tips.

Below is my thinking

maybe something point is the globalCompositeOperation property

javascript with fabric

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(bgImg, (bImg) => {     
    var bi = bImg.set({         
        top: bgHeight / 2 - this.globalBgSize / 2 - this.bgImgModifyTop,         
        left: bgWidth / 2 - this.globalBgSize / 2,         
        scaleX: this.globalBgSize / originWidth,         
        scaleY: this.globalBgSize / originHeight,         
        selectable: false     
    });     
    this.canvas.add(bi); 
}, {     
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous' 
});


fabric.Image.fromURL(mask, (hollowImg) => {     
    var hi = hollowImg.set({         
        top: bgHeight / 2 - this.globalBgSize / 2,         
        left: bgWidth / 2 - this.globalBgSize / 2,         
        scaleX: this.globalBgSize / originWidth,         
        scaleY: this.globalBgSize / originHeight,         
        selectable: false,         
        globalCompositeOperation: 'destination-in',         
        customMask: true     
    });     
    this.canvas.add(hi); 
}, {     
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous' 
});
```